# Why does my code output an error : Code is unreachable?

Tags: python, function

So I'm doing some coding for a project and I'm getting a weird error so plz help its probably something very simple but I can't seem to realize why.
This is psuedo code please do not be offended for not posting all of the code.

```
def Return_something_Wrapper(i, j, l):
    if True:
        def Return_somethin():
           ---

    else:
        return "Hello World"

    return Return_something
```

Comment: What is the error? Could you post the stacktrace please?

Comment: It's not about being offended; you are _expected_ by the site to post a [mcve]. You haven't

Comment: Do you have a typo, missing 'g' in  Return_somethin()

Comment: Thank you all Michael Bianconi answered the question.

Comment: Just to be clear this is not a Python error. It is probably an inspection by an IDE. Your code can execute fine, it is just letting you know of a logical issue in your code

Answer (score 2):

The `else` statement is unreachable because `if True:` will always execute.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help didn't think it was that. Thanks again.